# Why does certain Azure CLI commands require az login

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

In our VSTS release pipeline we want to call a powershell script that adds a function key for one of my Azure Functions (using the Key Management rest API).

I've created a script based on this article:
https://www.markheath.net/post/managing-azure-function-keys

```
Param(
    [string] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $ResourceGroup,
    [string] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $AppName,
    [string] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $FunctionName,
    [string] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $KeyName,
    [string] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $KeyValue
    )

    function getAuthenticationToken([string]$appName, [string]$resourceGroup)
    {
    $user = az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles -n $appName -g $resourceGroup `
            --query "[?publishMethod=='MSDeploy'].userName" -o tsv

    $pass = az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles -n $appName -g $resourceGroup `
            --query "[?publishMethod=='MSDeploy'].userPWD" -o tsv

    $pair = "$($user):$($pass)"
    $encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))

    $jwt = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://$appName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/functions/admin/token" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $encodedCreds)} -Method GET

    return $jwt
}

function setFunctionKey([string]$appName, [string]$functionName, [string] $keyName, [string]$keyValue, [string]$jwt)
{
    $body = (@{
        "name" = $keyName
        "value" = $keyValue
    } | ConvertTo-Json)

    #Setting the SecurityProtocol is a workaround for calling Azure APIs, I think?
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    try {
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://$appName.azurewebsites.net/admin/functions/$functionName/keys/$keyName/" `
            -Headers @{Authorization=("Bearer $jwt")} `
            -Method PUT `
            -ContentType "application/json" `
            -Body $body
    } catch {
        $_.Exception | Format-List -Force
    }
}

$jwt = getAuthenticationToken $AppName $ResourceGroup
setFunctionKey $AppName $FunctionName $KeyName $KeyValue $jwt
Write-Host "Specified key '$KeyName' has been added to $FunctionName"
```

Works locally, but when running it VSTS it gets and error when calling

```
$user = az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles -n $appName -g $resourceGroup `
                --query "[?publishMethod=='MSDeploy'].userName" -o tsv
```

with the message:

> ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.

We have other azure cli calls that works, ex: az cosmosdb database, so I guess our Service Principle connections are in place. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like we had an old powershell version containing a bug that keeps the old *service connection authentication* context when you create a new *service connection authentication*, which I did in this case.

So we updated powershell on our build agents and we got things going!

Answer (score 0):

From the document that you posted above, there is something you could miss.

> The first step is that we need to get the credentials to call the Kudu
>   API. **If you're authenticated with the Azure CLI**, you can do that by
>   calling the az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles command and
>   extracting the userName and userPWD for MSDeploy. You need to provide
>   the function app name and resource group name.

It seems that you should authenticate the Azure CLI before you use them.

Comment: I am under the assumption that all Azure CLI calls (that effects the environment) needs to be authenticated? I guess that are different kind of authentication "levels" (for lack of correct term) in this case?

Comment: @Kimmen Yes, if you want to use Azure CLI, you need to get authentication first.

Comment: Well, I got other azure cli commands working in other powershell tasks, ex "az cosmosdb database.." works. Setting the service connection options, isn't that suppose to authentication the powershell tasks?

Comment: @Kimmen Does you use the command `az cosmosdb database` in other session or in the same session? You can make sure if you already get authentication before executing the command.

Comment: The same session.